# MVC 4.0 WebApi Application and Mixed Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I am inquiring whether or not it is possible to provide both AD authentication and Basic for my WebApi Controller Services.  I intent is to have all internal (company) users authenticated with AD credentials (windows) for seamless sign on, but Basic Authentication for Mobile and External (non-company) users.  I'm finding information in regards to using either but not necessarily best approach to use both.  What I am not interested in doing is adding external users in AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach you could take is to create a custom action filter and register it globally.

Something along the lines of

```
public class MixedAuthenticationAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{ 
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext     actionContext)
    {
           //basic auth header check
           if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
           {
                 //no auth header run AD authentication process.
           } else {
                 //basic auth authentication
           }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably use the System.Web.Http.Authorizeattribute  here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute(v=vs.108).aspx. This kind of approach can sometimes be found in delegating handlers too.